# How to make JAWS not read an anchor tag as link but as button

Tags: html, angular, jaws-screen-reader

I have a requirement where I have an anchor tag in my HTML page.

```
<a aria-label="Back Button" class="secondary-button btn-font" title="Back" ngClass="btn-font"
            ngClass.xl="btn-font-xl" i18n-title='importantFacts@@back-button' id="backButton"
            i18n="@@importantFacts-back-button" routerLink="/apply-for-benefit/verification">
            Back
</a>
```

My requirement is that JAWS 2022 read it as 'Back Button', but JAWS reads it as 'Back Button link'. I know it's an anchor tag and it is supposed to read it as a link, but is there a way where it can read it as just 'Back Button' ?
I have already tried using  element and  but it does not fulfil some other requirement. Only an anchor tag does. I have also tried giving 'role' value as 'button' to the anchor tag, but again with this other requirement was not getting fulfilled.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you already tried the correct solution - set the [`role`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#button).

```
<a role="button">Back</a>
```

You don't need an `aria-label` because the contents of your link already has the text to announce, "Back".  And even if you wanted to have an aria-label, you should not specify the role in the label itself.  That is, don't use `aria-label="back button"` but instead just use `aria-label="back"`.

As a side note, links and buttons are quite different things.  Links should be used for navigation purposes - going to a new page or navigating to a different location on the same page.  Buttons should be used for "actions".

From a keyboard perspective, links only allow the <kbd>enter</kbd> key to select them whereas buttons allow both <kbd>enter</kbd> and <kbd>space</kbd>.  If you press <kbd>space</kbd> on a link, it will scroll the page (the default behavior on most browsers is to scroll the page when you press space).

Also, if a screen reader user hears "link", not only will they assume they are being navigated somewhere but they will also expect the browser's "back" button to take them back to where they were previously.  Buttons don't have that behavior.

So you really need to think about whether setting a `role="button"` on a link is the right thing to do instead of using a real `<button>`.  If you **do** want to use `role="button"` on a link, then you'll also need a keyboard event handler to allow the <kbd>space</kbd> to work as explained above.